# uitoggletool only shows shading when window not selected in MacOS

Tags: macos, matlab, click, uitoolbar

I'm trying to display any sign that a toggletool is active after pressing it, as usual, on matlab in MacOS. In Windows and Linux works fine but for some reason this happens on MacOS.

[image: Example of visually unselected uitoggletool after pressing - window active]

[image: Example of visually selected uitoggletool after pressing - another window is active instead]

After being pressed the only noticeable difference occurs only when the desired window is not selected (another window is selected instead).

What should I do? Is this some sort of MacOS theme? Can it be changed? Or I'm I forced to stupidly change the toggletool background each time it's pressed on a MacOS system, for it to be noticed?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what was the issue. It relates with the "Look and Feel" on the MacOS environment. Changing it to Plastic3D was enough:

`javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel('com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.Plastic3DLookAndFeel')`

It became a little blocky and somewhat retro but it suits my needs. However others can be used instead of this one. If you're interested check this [Undocumented Matlab page](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/modifying-matlab-look-and-feel) out: